# Send plain text to an USB Printer in Android

Tags: android, printing, usb

After reading this question: [Android USB Permissions Dialog never appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274285/android-usb-permissions-dialog-never-appears?s=5a0dbcc4-d342-4e73-a2ce-4fd6896a06a6) and doing some tests, I have the following problem :

I need to print to USB printer too (only plain text), I establish connection, dialog appears, but I don't now what to do after this. Can anybody help me with what must I do in openPort(aDevice)?

This is what I try:

```
................

if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(mDevice)){
final UsbDeviceConnection mConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(mDevice);
intf = mDevice.getInterface(0);
for (int i = 0; i < intf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
   UsbEndpoint ep = intf.getEndpoint(i);
   if (ep.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
           if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
           mEndpointBulkOut = ep;
               UsbDeviceConnection connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(mDevice);
           if(connection!=null)
           {
             Log.e(TAG," Conectado");
           }
           connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
           //Integer res = connection.bulkTransfer(mEndpointBulkOut, bytes, bytes.length, TIMEOUT);
           new Thread(new Runnable() 
           { 
           @Override 
           public void run() 
           { 
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
               Log.i(TAG, "in run thread"); 
               int b = mConnection.bulkTransfer(mEndpointBulkOut, bytes, bytes.length, 100000); 
               Log.i(TAG, "b-->" + b); 
               } 
               }).start(); 

               connection.releaseInterface(intf);
           break;
       }
 }
}
}
else
 mUsbManager.requestPermission(mDevice, mPermissionIntent);
break;`
```

.......

mConnection.bulkTransfer alwais return -1

Comment: did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your mConnection is null as it is another thread and that new thread doesn't have access to this UsbDeviceConnection.
Rebuild your application, follow [USB host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) more carefully or at least try to put mConnection in Singleton.

Also you can try to connect for a proxy like application: [Net2usb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.iwkowalow.net2usb)

Answer (score 0):

try this site, http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx. Download the sdk and try it.

Comment: I've tried, but not being a Star printer does not work, thanks